# TLS authentication with remote server

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, express-gateway

I'm trying to implement Express Gateway, what i need to do is to publish an API that routes to a TLS authenticated web service.

My question is, how do i configure the gateway so i can achieve this flow:

1- Client send request to http://my.api

2- Gateway takes HTTP Request and sends it to a TLS authtenticated webservice

3- Take the response and send it back to the client

My apologizes for the poor english.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's nothing special here, just make the gateway listen on the http interface and use the proxy policy to the https server targeting.